# How to set JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri outside of classpath in Log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2

In Log4j2's JsonTemplateLayout, I have no problem using eventTemplateUri: "classpath:LayoutTemplate.jsson" with json file located in rc/main/resources.
However, I would need to keep this file outside of class path. so I would like to use  file location something like he way we add log fileName: c:\...

But it's throwing an error when I use eventTemplateUri: "C:\ ....\LayoutTemplate.json"

rror message is " Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.layout.template.json.JsonTemplateLa
yout for element JsonTemplateLayout: java.lang.RuntimeException: failed reading URI: C:...
Did I miss anything here?
is it possible to place this json file outside of class path?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

All `*Uri` configuration knobs in `JsonTemplateLayout` expect a URI string. In your case, the URI *scheme* is missing. The `eventTemplateUri` should look like `file:///C:/path/to/LayoutTemplate.json` in your case. For internals, see how `o.a.l.l.l.template.json.util.Uris.readUri(String,Charset)` is implemented.

Comment: Actually, I expect the url needs to be file:///C:/path/to/LayoutTemplate.json. The first two slashes are required to make it a valid URL and the third is to separate the hostname field from the rest of the url. Since no hostname is provided it is simply omitted and you end up with 3 slashes before the drive letter. Although wikipedia indicates that using a single slash could work I've come to stick with 3 slashes on Windows to ensure it will work.

Comment: @rgoers, thanks, makes sense, updated the answer.

Comment: file:///C:/path/to/LayoutTemplate.json worked for me when using windows. 
When i tried file:///home/path/to/LayoutTemplate.json using linux it did not work. Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: @Shorty123, just use two slashes (i.e., `file://home/path`) on Linux?

Comment: Actually it worked before with three slashes the problem was a typo in a child element. 
Is it possible to enable log4j logging to see problems like that ?